# Autoplay html video on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've searched across the internet and found some good examples but for some reason when I try to implement them with my code it's not working. I can't figure out what I seem to be doing wrong..

(I'm sorry for the dutch class names, hope it isn't too confusing). Sorry If I'm being really dumb about this.

HTML:

```
<div class="drievijfde-wrapper portfolio-wrapper">
    <div class="single-item singlevidjs drievijfde-padding" style="background-image:url(img/work-placeholder.png); background-position: center center; background-size: cover;">
        <video loop preload="auto" id="portfolio-vid">
            <source src="video/test reel_1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>  
        <a href="#">
            <div class="metadata">
                Interior Lamps
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var figure = $(".singlevidjs").hover( hoverVideo, hideVideo );

function hoverVideo(e) {  
    $('video', this).get(0).play(); 
}

function hideVideo(e) {
    $('video', this).get(0).pause(); 
}
```

Comment: first of all, pls be a bit more detailed when describing a problem: my code is not working, will help nobody ;)  
anyway, here is a working jsbin:  
http://jsbin.com/cupusesoce/edit?html,js,output  
so the issue must be: jQuery is not loaded or an issue with your video :)

Comment: it is working [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8r396y6u/) check your `jquery` added?

Comment: Yes! I messed up the Jquery somewhere, I feel really bad now. thank you for pointing that out. And Yea @DincaAdrian I cringed when I did it aswell but it was just for testing. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You can use following `jQuery` code for this

```
$('#portfolio-vid').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).get(0).play();
}).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).get(0).pause();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is little old but I like to add answer for this

```html
<div style="width:500px;height:500px;">
  <video id="portfolio-vid" controls autoplay width="400" height="400">
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>    
</div>
```

```js
<script>
document.getElementById("portfolio-vid").addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
            this.play();
    });
    
        document.getElementById("portfolio-vid").addEventListener("mouseleave",function() {
        this.pause();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution without any js would be to just add:

```
onmouseover="this.play()"
onmouseout="this.pause()"
```

to a `video` element.
So in your code it would look like:

```
<video loop preload="auto" id="portfolio-vid" onmouseover="this.play()" onmouseout="this.pause()">
    <source src="video/test reel_1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

If you would like to restart video each time you could do:

```
onmouseout="this.pause();this.currentTime=0;"
```